# I'm building a program that takes an undefined number of inputs, store them in arraylists, and print only before exiting the program the variables

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I can't wrap my head around it: i call for a loop, that at the end asks the user wether they want to repeat the process. But in doing so i fundamentally reset the counter of the loop as i call the entire method, if the user wants to insert another set of data Therefore i cannot fill my array beyond the index 0, and introducing a global variable that manages the amount of times the code has been repeated doesn't help either.
Here is the code:

```
  public class Main  {
    public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int counter = 0; 
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        inputdata();
        
    }
    public static void repeat (ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> ages, ArrayList<Double> passinggrades) {
        System.out.println("Want to insert another student? y/n");
        String goon = input.nextLine();
        if (goon.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("thank you for using the program. exiting...");
            showdata(names, ages, passinggrades);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (goon.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            
            inputdata();
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input: " + goon + " is not y or n");
            repeat(names, ages, passinggrades);
        }
    }
    public static void inputdata () {
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Double> passinggrades = new ArrayList<Double>();
        
        for (int i = counter; i != -1; i++) {
            System.out.print("insert name here: ");
            String name = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("insert age here: ");
            int age = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("insert passing grade here: ");
            double passinggrade = input.nextDouble();
            Student student = new Student(name, age, passinggrade);
            names.add(i, student.name);
            ages.add(i, student.age);
            passinggrades.add(i, student.passinggrade);
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(counter);
            counter ++;
            repeat(names, ages, passinggrades);
        }
    }
    public static void showdata (ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> ages, ArrayList<Double> passinggrades) {
        System.out.print("Name |");
        System.out.print("Age |");
        System.out.print("Grade |");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(names.get(i)+ " |");
            System.out.print(ages.get(i)+ " |");
            System.out.print(passinggrades.get(i)+ " |");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The Student class:

```
public class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
    double passinggrade;
    
    
    Student(String name, int age, double passinggrade){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.passinggrade = passinggrade;
    }
}
```

The error that the compiler gives when I try to insert an element beyond the first:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:756)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:481)
    at simpleconstructor2.Main.inputdata(Main.java:42)
    at simpleconstructor2.Main.repeat(Main.java:22)
    at simpleconstructor2.Main.inputdata(Main.java:48)
    at simpleconstructor2.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Comment: `for (int i = counter; i != -1; i++)`  Does this loop even ever end?  It seems like `counter` is `0` so `i` starts at `0` and only ever increments, how will it hit `-1` without wrapping through the integer limit

Comment: there is also some redundancy in your code. Why have 3 arraylists for name, age, and passingGrade? Have one arraylist for students and store the student object in it and access each of the 3 fields when needed. Also, whenever you call inputData() in repeat(), you essentially "erase" all the data in your arrayLists by making a new arrayList for each if i m not mistaken.

Comment: no idea whats wrong with a simple for-loop as such: ```for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {        }``` that you would need to overcomplicate it

Comment: it doesn't have to hit -1, i only put it there because i had to, the only way of ending the program is to type n, and yes, i know i erase all my data in the arraylist, i just don't know how not to do that.

Comment: You should never program so that your logic only works if you hit a `System.exit(0);` (you _really_ should not ever use this unless you know what you are doing) If you find yourself "only putting stuff there" because it won't compile without it, you need to rethink what you are doing to begin with, as the design is definitely wrong.

Comment: if you want to keep repeating stuff without stopping until a very specific condition, try using a while loop or do-while loop. would definite help clean up your code and all the recursive calls

Comment: I just realized, you are using 3 `ArrayList` instead of just using your `Student` class and using an `ArrayList<Student>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drafted a quick version of your code for inputdata() which cuts out the need for repeat().

```
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();  //declare and initialize your arrayList outside the loop so it is not redeclared and replaced in each iteration.
    while (true){
        System.out.print("insert name here: ");
        String name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("insert age here: ");
        int age = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("insert passing grade here: ");
        double passinggrade = input.nextDouble();
        Student student = new Student(name, age, passinggrade);
        //redundant-------------------------------------
        //names.add(i, student.name);
        //ages.add(i, student.age);
        //passinggrades.add(i, student.passinggrade);
        //----------------------------------------------
        students.add(student);
        input.nextLine();

        //you can probably fit this in a boolean method that will break or return depending on value of goon
        System.out.println("Want to insert another student? y/n");
        String goon = input.nextLine();
        if (goon.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
            System.out.println("thank you for using the program. exiting...");
            showdata(students);  //modify your showdata() method accordingly for an ArrayList of Student
            break;
        }else if (goon.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
            continue;
        }else {
            System.out.println("Wrong input: " + goon + " is not y or n");
            continue;
        }
    }
```